# Get modifier keys to show in Screencast when they are pressed by themselves

Tags: add-on

Is there a way to get keys like SHIFT and CTRL to show in Screencast when they are pressed by themselves? This would be very beneficial for the viewer in cases like where one first selects one object, then holds down SHIFT and then selects another object. In this case, the SHIFT held by itself doesn't get displayed, so the viewer is left not knowing exactly what was done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no setting which would allow displaying modifier keys alone. I looked into the source and the modifier keys are disabled in line 550 of the screencast addon:

```
ignore_keys = ['LEFT_SHIFT', 'RIGHT_SHIFT', 'LEFT_ALT',
         'RIGHT_ALT', 'LEFT_CTRL', 'RIGHT_CTRL', 'TIMER',
         'MOUSEMOVE', 'INBETWEEN_MOUSEMOVE']
```

You could right click on the screencast control to open the python source in the text editor and remove the keys want. Click register in the text editor's header and run the script. (Of course you could also save the modified version in into the blender installation folder).

[image]

Comment: Note that two events will be raised - the modifier keydown event and the second key you press with that modifier set (e.g. `event.shift`).